# How can I make my code to update mirrors in Puppet more clean?

Tags: puppet

this looks like lots of code and could be more efficient (Zesty & Xenial )? I would like to get it shorter and easier to manage for future Versions (Ubuntu 18....) Can you please support thanks

```
 $mirrors         = {
    'xenial_main' => {
      location      => 'http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu',
      release       => 'xenial',
      repos         => ['main', 'restricted'],
      architectures => ['i386','amd64'],
      key           => ['40976EAF437D05B5','3B4FE6ACC0B21F32'],
      keyserver     => 'keyserver.ubuntu.com',
      with_udebs    => true,
    },
    'xenial_main_updates' => {
      location      => 'http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu',
      release       => 'xenial-updates',
      repos         => ['main', 'restricted'],
      architectures => ['i386','amd64'],
      key           => ['40976EAF437D05B5','3B4FE6ACC0B21F32'],
      keyserver     => 'keyserver.ubuntu.com',
      with_udebs    => true,
    },
    'xenial_universe' => {
      location      => 'http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu',
      release       => 'xenial',
      repos         => ['universe'],
      architectures => ['i386','amd64'],
      key           => ['40976EAF437D05B5','3B4FE6ACC0B21F32'],
      keyserver     => 'keyserver.ubuntu.com',
      with_udebs    => true,
    },
  'zesty_main' => {
      location      => 'http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu',
      release       => 'zesty',
      repos         => ['main', 'restricted'],
      architectures => ['i386','amd64'],
      key           => ['40976EAF437D05B5','3B4FE6ACC0B21F32'],
      keyserver     => 'keyserver.ubuntu.com',
      with_udebs    => true,
    },
    'zesty_main_updates' => {
      location      => 'http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu',
      release       => 'zesty-updates',
      repos         => ['main', 'restricted'],
      architectures => ['i386','amd64'],
      key           => ['40976EAF437D05B5','3B4FE6ACC0B21F32'],
      keyserver     => 'keyserver.ubuntu.com',
      with_udebs    => true,
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an iterator? Docs here: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_iteration.html

It's most basic version would be:

```
['xenial','zesty'] = $ubuntu_releases

$ubuntu_releases.each |String $release| {

  $mirrors         = {
    "${release}_main" => {
      location      => 'http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu',
      release       => $release,
      repos         => ['main', 'restricted'],
      architectures => ['i386','amd64'],
      key           => ['40976EAF437D05B5','3B4FE6ACC0B21F32'],
      keyserver     => 'keyserver.ubuntu.com',
      with_udebs    => true,
    },
    "${release}_main_updates" => {
      location      => 'http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu',
      release       => "${release}-updates",
      repos         => ['main', 'restricted'],
      architectures => ['i386','amd64'],
      key           => ['40976EAF437D05B5','3B4FE6ACC0B21F32'],
      keyserver     => 'keyserver.ubuntu.com',
      with_udebs    => true,
    },
    "${release}_universe" => {
      location      => 'http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu',
      release       => $release,
      repos         => ['universe'],
      architectures => ['i386','amd64'],
      key           => ['40976EAF437D05B5','3B4FE6ACC0B21F32'],
      keyserver     => 'keyserver.ubuntu.com',
      with_udebs    => true,
    },
  }
}
```

But you could even go further and iterate through the hash as the only thing that changes is the with_udebs, release name and hash title?

Comment: I thought you would have to assign the value of `$mirrors` to the RValue from the lambda iterator. Does this form work?